# Adjusting upload button sit on the same column with other upload button?

Tags: html, css

I have full page of list to upload document. But my upload document page kind of look messy and the upload button are unorganized.

I want to achieve a page that all the `upload` button sit at the same column. I tried to put the button in another `<div>` but the button got push to the next line.

How do I achieve the output like this ?

```
Copy of Latest Certificate ARDSFGH                  Upload
Copy of Individual Identification Card/Passport     Upload
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 mb-30">
                <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Copy of Latest Certificate ARDSFGH</b></label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-30 choose_attachment">Upload</button>
                    <input type="file" id="attachment1" hidden>
                        <div class="tab-content col-12" id="myTabContent-2">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                                <div id="choose1" class="row p-1"></div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 mb-30">
                <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Copy of Individual Identification Card/Passport</b></label>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-30 choose_attachment2">Upload</button>
                    <input type="file" id="attachment2" hidden>
                        <div class="tab-content col-12" id="myTabContent-2">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                                <div id="choose2" class="row p-1"></div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add another col to set upload buttons in same position

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mb-30">
                <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Copy of Latest Certificate ARDSFGH</b></label>
                  
               </div>
             <div class="col-sm-3 text-left">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-30 choose_attachment">Upload</button>
                    <input type="file" id="attachment1" hidden>
                        <div class="tab-content col-12" id="myTabContent-2">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                                <div id="choose1" class="row p-1"></div>    
                            </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mb-30">
                <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Copy of Individual Identification Card/Passport</b></label>
                  
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 text-left">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info w-30 choose_attachment2">Upload</button>
                    <input type="file" id="attachment2" hidden>
                        <div class="tab-content col-12" id="myTabContent-2">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="addCustodian" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="addCustodian-tab">
                                <div id="choose2" class="row p-1"></div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```